# Suppressing output of Node.js util.debug(), util.log() etc

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a Node app at the moment, and one of the modules I'm including has loads of util.debug() and util.log() messages from the [util module](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html) peppered around it. I would like to suppress the CLI output of these methods without hacking the contrib module itself- is there any easy way of doing this?

I believe these methods write to stderr, but I don't want to suppress all error messages, just those specific ones. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What module are you using?  I'd highly suggest contacting the author about removing those (possibly with a patch that removes them for them).  Also, check for a verbosity flag, the default should definitely not be verbose though.

Comment: This: https://github.com/rollbar/node_rollbar (notably in lib/api.js) - I have spoken to the authors before, so I may be able to suggest/pull request it, but I was just curious as to whether there was a way of over-riding the output of util after it's already been required/initialised...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After briefly reviewing the code of node_rollbar, it does not seem like it has a verbosity setting unless there is something configurable for the util module that I am not aware of. It does seem like all cases except 1 are only for error based scenarios.

I agree that contacting the author or better yet submitting a pull request with an adequate solution would be best. However, one approach that is not a great idea is utilizing a dependency injection module like [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire) to overwrite the use of util within the node_rollbar module.

Comment: I can't imagine there'll be many responses to this question, so for now at least I'll accept your answer (thanks!). The rewire module looks interesting, +1 for that- although it's still a rather dodgy method. Do you know of any way of suppressing stderr output in general whilst running a node js application, by the way?

Comment: Not particularly, though I do know that the forever module lets you output stdout and stderr separately. I want to say that stdout may have also included stderr but I can't recall. There may be some logging modules that can tackle this, but me not sure.